# In Stata, how do I correctly use if statement inside foreach loop?

Tags: loops, foreach, stata

I'm trying to use `if` statements to assign correct labels for my graphs created inside `foreach` loop in Stata:

```
foreach major in var1 var2 {

    * conditional labelling
    if "`major'" == "var1" {
        local ytitle "title for var1"
    }
    else if "`major" == "var2" {
        local ytitle "title for var2"
    }

    di in red "____________"
    di in red "`major'"
    di in red "`ytitle'"
    di in red "____________"

}
```

The output of this exercise is

```
____________
var1
should be var1
____________
____________
var2
should be var1
____________
```

My question is - why isn't the local changed in the second instance of the loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The example is a little confusing, as the words "should be" in the output should be (so to speak) "title for", matching the code. That aside, your bug is an unmatched single quote. Try

```
foreach major in var1 var2 {

    * conditional labelling
    if "`major'" == "var1" {
       local ytitle "title for var1"
    }
    else if "`major'" == "var2" {
       local ytitle "title for var2"
    }

    di in red "____________"
    di in red "`major'"
    di in red "`ytitle'"
    di in red "____________"

}
```

Comment: Thanks Nick! It seems I failed on Stata quotes again :/